# Getting data from outside the form

Tags: delphi

I have a main form and tabsheet with some pages in it.

On 1st page there is a labeled edit,say,edit1. On 2 page there is a button that opens a new window(form). 
On this form there will be another labeled edit say edit2.

Question is : How can I  compare value from edit1 with that of edit2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have:

1. A reference to the main form, say `MainForm: TMainForm`, and
2. a reference to the other form, say `OtherForm: TOtherForm`.

Then you can write:

```
if MainForm.Edit1.Text = OtherForm.Edit2.Text then
  ....
```

That will work. But it would be better if your two forms exposed the text by way of public properties. That would avoid you needing to poke around at their internals.

Comment: Do I have to include Unit1 in uses of Unit2 ?

Comment: At the point where you make the comparisons, you need both units to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

If the form is displayed by show() a possible solution might be this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  form2.Show();
  if self.edit1.text= form2.edit2.text
    then ShowMessage('Equals!');
end;
```

However, If form is a DMI child, this solution does not make much sense because there is no guarantee that the value changes. This works if you use ShowModal().

Comment: In terms of the comparison, it doesn't matter whether `Show` or `ShowModal` is called. The reason your code does not make much sense is that the test is in the wrong place, probably. There's no compelling reason to imagine that the check has to be made at the point where `Show` is called, or the point where `ShowModal` returns. One more thing. The property is named `Text` rather than `Caption`.

Comment: The controls are not labels, are edits. Thus the property is text. The form is an MDI child. Thanks David!

Comment: in my program its not good idea to use show(), but thank u anyway.